# using jquery click eveny from within an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to add a click event to a `<span>` in the DOM but the click event sits in an object

i have this html

```
<html>
<body>
   <span id="meToLog">hello-world </span>
  </body>

 <script>
  function makeObj(){
   this.logMe= $("#meToLog").click(function(){
     console.log("shoot")
    }) 
   }
   const obj = new makeObj()
     obj.logMe // i want this to listen to click event 


   </script>
</html>
```

Comment: That "object" doesn't make sense to me.  What do you expect the *result value* of setting the click event to be?  What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: in the original code im requiring  the object( with the click events) to the main.js from an outer javascript file  i want to make eventListener to listen from within an object if it possible

Comment: It's certainly possible to "use an object" in a general sense, but it's still not clear at all from your example what you're actually trying to do or why.  Code within the object can set the click event, or a function property of an object can be used as a click event, or any number of other things can happen.  But what isn't clear is what you *want* to happen.

Comment: i want to happen, when i click on <span id="meToLog"> it will console.log("shoot")  the listener must sit in an object

Comment: You don't need an object for that.  Just set the click handler: `$("#meToLog").click(function(){ console.log("shoot"); });`

Comment: Per your edit: `"the listener must sit in an object"` - What does that ***mean***?

Comment: this is an example! i know i cant just write the listener in the global  main.js file but the important thing is that i want to require them from an outside javascript file im not searching other solution unless what im asking not possible

Comment: Things that *make sense* are possible.  But since you can't even describe what you're trying to do, then I don't see how anybody can show you how to do it.  `"i know i cant just write the listener in the global main.js file"` - Why can't you?  What's the ***actual problem*** you're trying to solve?

Comment: The main issue here is that what you're storing in the `logMe` property is not a function, is just a reference to a jquery object, the span in this case. That's what jquery's click method returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment the problem is what you're storing in the constructor's property `logMe`. The `click()` method returns a jquery object, the span in this case, but the click handler is never attached to it.

http://api.jquery.com/click/

What you have right now in your constructor is this:

```
function makeObj(){
  this.logMe= $("#meToLog").click(function(){
    console.log("shoot")
  }) 
}

const myObj = new makeObj();
// test what logMe is
console.log(myObj.logMe); // returns the jquery object [span#meToLog]
```

One solution is to transform your `logMe` property into a method in order to attach the click handler to the element:

```
function makeObj(){
  this.logMe= function(){
    $("#meToLog").click(function(){
      console.log("shoot")
    });
  }
}

// create a new instance
const myObj = new makeObj();
// attach the click handler
myObj.logMe();
// now click on the span and the log should be there
```

This sample seems to do what you're after:

https://jsfiddle.net/ndkzjdyb/

---

I forgot to mention that since functions are first class objects in javascript, you can pass the id string and a specific handler to your constructor method to make it more dynamic. Check this revision of the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ndkzjdyb/2/

---

#### Edit

Based on @dfsq's comment I updated the fiddles to avoid adding more than one event handler if the method is ran more than once:

#### Static Method

https://jsfiddle.net/ndkzjdyb/3/

#### Dynamic Method

https://jsfiddle.net/ndkzjdyb/4/

Comment: Here is a problem with your code: `myObj.logMe(); myObj.logMe(); myObj.logMe();`

Comment: @dfsq Yep, that certainly should be a concern. Perhaps use the second snippet using on and off in order to remove the event handler for the object, if it has one already. But is Sunday!! ;) Also I would use an event emitter instead of this, but the question was pointing in this direction.

Comment: @dfsq I updated the fiddles to avoid attaching more than one handler. Thanks for pointing it out, cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set onclick event on the span as bellow

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#meToLog").click(function(){
        console.log("shoot");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="meToLog">click me to log</span>
</body>
</html>
```

and this as you do by creating object's function

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function makeObj(){
   this.logMe = function(){
     console.log("shoot");
    }
   }
   const obj = new makeObj();

   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#meToLog").click(function(){
        obj.logMe();
    });
});
   </script>
  </head>
<body>
   <span id="meToLog">hello-world </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry but this is not a good idea you do not attach event in the dom but only in the javascript